# Guest user functionality in rails app with devise + storing in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I want users to be able to utilize certain functions of my app without having to create an account - pretty standard. For instance, I have a listmaking function where a user can create a list and add items to it. I'm using current_user a lot in my controllers and views to do this type of thing, and whenever a non-user tries, it predictably throws all sorts of errors. I understand that Devise can handle this by storing user attributes in a session and then remembering with cookies, correct? My question is this: How do I store current_user attributes in the session? I've searched for docs on this and SO for similar questions, but haven't had much luck. Feel free to direct me to a good resource if this has already been hashed out (I'm sure it has, somewhere). Here's my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Please let me know if I can clarify what I'm trying to do, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching, I think I've found a good solution to this problem. I found it in the devise docs on github regarding guest_users. Here's the link:https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Here's what devise recommends:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  # if user is logged in, return current_user, else return guest_user
  def current_or_guest_user
    if current_user
      if session[:guest_user_id]
        logging_in
        guest_user.destroy
        session[:guest_user_id] = nil
      end
      current_user
    else
      guest_user
    end
  end

  # find guest_user object associated with the current session,
  # creating one as needed
  def guest_user
    # Cache the value the first time it's gotten.
    @cached_guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound # if session[:guest_user_id] invalid
     session[:guest_user_id] = nil
     guest_user
  end

  private

  # called (once) when the user logs in, insert any code your application needs
  # to hand off from guest_user to current_user.
  def logging_in
    # For example:
    # guest_comments = guest_user.comments.all
    # guest_comments.each do |comment|
      # comment.user_id = current_user.id
      # comment.save!
    # end
  end

  def create_guest_user
    u = User.create(:name => "guest", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@example.com")
    u.save!(:validate => false)
    session[:guest_user_id] = u.id
    u
  end

end
```

I think this is a good solution. I'll need to rework some part of my app that use current_user and rework to accept both guest_user and current_user.

Comment: Nice you got it working, though the implementation is for guest user which is quite different from question :)

Comment: I think it's actually exactly in line with what I stated my goal was, "I want users to be able to utilize certain functions of my app without having to create an account".

Comment: Though I'll admit the title isn't very good. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your concern. It's inconvenient to miss current_user when lots of functionalities relying on that.

The first step is to create a current_user in whatever circumstance.

```
class ApplicationController

  def current_user
    super || User.new
  end

end
```

By this setting, when there is no current_user available in Devise, you create a new instance of User for this visitor automatically.

The second step, you can now store information of current_user into session as usual. I'm not a big fan of session, but it's still of usage when you really need it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer Billy. This does indeed do as you say. It should work well I think, except for one thing. It makes the `user_signed_in?` method useless, as every user is now considered signed in. I'm not sure how to get around that. Thoughts?

Comment: No, `User.new` will create a new user in memory, just like the object in `#new` form. It is not saved to db, and no way be signed in :)

Comment: The reason I ask, is because I have a user_signed_in? method that doesn't function correctly - it is always saying that user is signed in. Thoughts?

Comment: I have not checked the specific method but you can override it and  check if user is persisted at first. Like `def user_signed_in?; persisted || super; end;`

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't really want to override this method, because it's important to other aspects of my app.

Comment: That's all about level of confidence.

Comment: After searching through devise docs for a lonnnnggg time, I think I've found a good solution. I'm posting as an answer. +1 for your time and effort.